# Tinting background image with linear-gradient doesn't work

Tags: css, background-image, linear-gradients

I am trying to tint an image with a transparent linear gradient. 
Dev tools say my property is invalid. If I get rid of the gradient, the image shows up fine. Is there something I'm missing?

```
body {
    background: linear-gradient (rgba(255,0,0,0.45),rgba(255,0,0,0.45)),
                url('Fabric-4.png');
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: large;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use prefix's for different browsers while using css gradient propery,
check this code.

```
body { 
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255,0,0,0.45), rgba(255,0,0,0.45));
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: large;
}
```

Comment: yeah, that didn't work...with chrome you don't need vendor prefixes...thank you for trying though

Answer (score 0):

This is simply because your markup fails. You have a single space too much. Remove the space between `linear-gradient` and `(` and you will see the issue sorted. I added the working code below, and marked it up to my own preference.

[Here's a pen with the working example (and a different image).](http://codepen.io/matiasvad/pen/ogOqLz?editors=010) Try adding the space live in the pen, and see everything disappear again. :)

```
body {
    background: 
        linear-gradient(
            rgba(255,0,0,0.45),
            rgba(255,0,0,0.45)),
            url('Fabric-4.png');
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: large;
}
```